# Cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update the account's bill, but this error came out 
"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraints fails". I've searched for the reason and most of it stated that it's because inserting value that are not available in the primary table. However I in my form for the bill registration, i use dropdown box that contains account number from that primary table,yet it still has this error.

the form

```
<div id="contact_form">


                    <form method="post" action="proses_daftar_bill.php" name="maklumat_bill" oninput= "JumlahBayaran.value = parseFloat(AmaunCaj.value) + parseFloat(AmaunTunggakan.value) + parseFloat(AmaunPenalti.value) + parseFloat(AmaunPelbagai.value) + parseFloat(CajPF.value) + parseFloat(GST.value)">



                        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <label for="NoAkaun">Nombor Akaun</label>
                        <?php
                        require ("dbase.php");
                        $sql    = "SELECT NoAkaun FROM maklumatakaun";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        echo "<select name='NoAkaun' id='NoAkaun' class='input_field' required /><option></option>";
                        while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "<option value=".$kod['NoAkaun'].">" .$kod['NoAkaun']."</OPTION>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";

                        ?>  
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><label for="BulanBil">Tarikh Bil:</label> </td>
                        <td><select class="required bill_caj" name="BulanBil" id="BulanBil" width="300px" required/>
                        <option value="">--Pilih Bulan--</option>
                        <option value="Januari">Januari</option>
                        <option value="Februari">Februari</option>
                        <option value="Mac">Mac</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="Mei">Mei</option>
                        <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                        <option value="Julai">Julai</option>
                        <option value="Ogos">Ogos</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="Oktober">Oktober</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="Disember">Disember</option>
                        </select></td>

                        <label for="TahunBil"></label><td><input type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" id="TahunBil" name="TahunBil" class="required year_field" placeholder="Tahun" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" required/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>    
                        <td><label for="AmaunCaj">Amaun</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  name="AmaunCaj" id="AmaunCaj"  class="bill_caj" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" required></td>


                        <td><label for="AmaunTunggakan">Tunggakan</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="AmaunTunggakan" id="AmaunTunggakan"  class="bill_caj" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" required></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><label for="AmaunPenalti">Penalti</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text"   name="AmaunPenalti" id="AmaunPenalti"  class="bill_caj" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')"required></td>


                        <td><label for="AmaunPelbagai">Pelbagai</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="AmaunPelbagai" id="AmaunPelbagai"  class="bill_caj" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')"required></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><label for="GST">GST</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="GST" id="GST"  class="bill_caj" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')"required></td>
                        </tr>



                    <tr>
                    <td><label for="checkbox_pf">PF<input type="checkbox" onclick="codename()" name="checkbox_pf" value="ON"></label></td>



                    <td><label for="BacaanPF">Bacaan PF:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="BacaanPF" name="BacaanPF" class="bill_caj" value="0" disabled onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><label for="CajPF">Caj PF:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="CajPF" name="CajPF" class="bill_caj" value="0" disabled onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')"></td>
                    </tr>




                        <tr>
                        <td><label for="JumlahBayaran">Jumlah Bayaran:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="JumlahBayaran" name="JumlahBayaran" class="bill_caj" for="AmaunCaj AmaunTunggakan" step="any" readonly></td>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                        </tr>






                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Daftar" id="submit" name="register-submit" class="submit_btn " /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Batal" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                    </form>
```

the sql

```
<?php
require("dbase.php"); 

if ($_POST) {

    $TarikhData         = isset($_POST['TarikhData'])       ? $_POST['TarikhData'] : '';
    $username           = isset($_POST['username'])         ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $NoAkaun            = isset($_POST['NoAkaun'])          ? $_POST['NoAkaun'] : '';
    $BulanBil           = isset($_POST['BulanBil'])         ? $_POST['BulanBil'] : '';
    $TahunBil           = isset($_POST['TahunBil'])         ? $_POST['TahunBil'] : '';
    $AmaunCaj           = isset($_POST['AmaunCaj'])         ? $_POST['AmaunCaj'] : '';
    $AmaunTunggakan     = isset($_POST['AmaunTunggakan'])   ? $_POST['AmaunTunggakan'] : '';
    $AmaunPenalti       = isset($_POST['AmaunPenalti'])     ? $_POST['AmaunPenalti'] : '';
    $AmaunPelbagai      = isset($_POST['AmaunPelbagai'])    ? $_POST['AmaunPelbagai'] : '';
    $GST                = isset($_POST['GST'])              ? $_POST['GST'] : '';
    $BacaanPF           = isset($_POST['BacaanPF'])         ? $_POST['BacaanPF'] : '';
    $CajPF              = isset($_POST['CajPF'])            ? $_POST['CajPF'] : '';
    $JumlahBayaran      = isset($_POST['JumlahBayaran'])    ? $_POST['JumlahBayaran'] : '';




    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO maklumatbilakaun VALUES ('', '$TarikhData' , '$username' , '$NoAkaun' , '$BulanBil' , '$TahunBil' ,'$AmaunCaj' ,'$AmaunTunggakan' ,'$AmaunPenalti' ,'$AmaunPelbagai' , '$GST' , '$BacaanPF' ,'$CajPF' ,'$JumlahBayaran')");
    echo mysql_error();
}






?>
```

what actually is the problem?

Comment: Please remove the code that is not directly linked to the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you checked that `NoAkaun` is the only foreign key constraint on `maklumatbilakaun`?

Comment: "NoAkaun" is the only foreign key in maklumatbilakaun. I used drop down box where the options contains account number that have been registered earlier. And yes i've included in my insert statement : $NoAkaun. @adamdc78

Comment: Make sure that you're getting the value and not the index from the drop down; you may also be getting encoding funkiness or extra whitespace.

Comment: how can i ensure that sir ? @adamdc78

Comment: Quick and dirty in the absence of a debugger, echo it in the line before the query (surrounded by a delimiter such as `~`).

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but i don't understand what you mean, can you explain it more? sorry for the inconvenience @adamdc78

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68250/discussion-between-adamdc78-and-itsfawwaz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specifying the columns for your values in your insert statement, you're prone to having your values being inserted in the wrong columns.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
maklumatbilakaun (TarikhData, username, NoAkaun, BulanBil, TahunBil, AmaunCaj, AmaunTunggakan, AmaunPenalti, AmaunPelbagai, GST, BacaanPF, CajPF, JumlahBayaran)
VALUES ('$TarikhData' , '$username' , '$NoAkaun' , '$BulanBil' , '$TahunBil' ,'$AmaunCaj' ,'$AmaunTunggakan' ,'$AmaunPenalti' ,'$AmaunPelbagai' , '$GST' , '$BacaanPF' ,'$CajPF' ,'$JumlahBayaran')");
```

You'll also need to supply `DEFAULT` to columns instead of empty values or omit the columns when building your insert statement (I prefer the latter approach, although I'm not sure how efficient string concatenation is in php).

Comment: ahh, finally the solution to my problem, much appreciated sir.